# How to put variable on nested loop?

Tags: c, nested-loops

I want to put make a box of variable. I don't know where I make a mistake?

```
int i;

for(i=0;i<=w;i++) {
    printf("%c ",c);
    int j;
    for(j=0;j<=h;j++){
        printf("%c ",c);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

I want my output like this :

```
L L L L L
L L L L L
L L L L L
```

Comment: The first "mistake" is your formatting, and the lack of consistent indentation, as well as putting multiple statements on a single line.

Comment: Remove the first `printf`

Comment: As for the code itself, what does it do that it isn't supposed to do? What happens when you run it? What is the actual output you get from it? Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). And if possible also please try to create a [mre] to show us. Then please [edit] your question to improve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a modified version of your code (the comments in the code point out the changes I've made):

```
int i;
for(i=0;i<h;i++){ //changed <= to < (since i is starting from 0) or it would've printed an extra row of L's
    //also, it should be i<h not i<w (considering h is the height of the rectangle)
    //removed printf("%c ",c); from here as well to avoid printing an extra L at the beginning of each row
    int j;
    for(j=0;j<w;j++){ //changed <= to < in this case too or it would've printed an extra L at the end of each row
    //changed j<h to j<w as well (considering w is the width of the rectangle)
        printf("%c ",c);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```